# Concordance, surgery and homology cobordism

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, surgery-theory

In this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366561/relating-smooth-concordance-and-homology-cobordism-via-integral-surgeries), we discuss the relation between the concordance of knots in $S^3$ and the integral homology cobordism.

Following its notation, assume that knots $K_0$ and $K_1$ in $S^3$ are concordant. Then the $3$-manifolds $S^3_{n} (K_0)$ and $S^3_{n} (K_1)$ are integral homology cobordant.

Now we perform one more (say $m$) integral surgery on concordant knots in $S^3_{n} (K_0)$ and $S^3_{n} (K_1)$.

My questions are:

1. Do we still have an integral homology cobordism between the new resulting $3$-manifolds?
2. Is there any restriction on $m$?
3. The integer $n$ can be zero?

Comment: What do you mean by "some null-homologous knots"? If you choose two random null-homologous knots (say, a trefoil and an unknot, each contained in a ball), then there's no reason to expect a rational homology cobordism.

Comment: Sorry for unclarity. I edited the post.